# Disabling Warnings

Tags: vimrc

Scenario:

View a file with `view src/somefile.c` in one terminal

Edit the same file with `vi src/somefile.c` in a second terminal

After saving modifications to the file with the vi instance in the second terminal, changing focus to the view instance in the first terminal causes the following warning to appear at the bottom in the view instance:

```
W11: Warning: File "src/somefile.c" has changed since editing started
See ":help W11" for more info.
[O]K, (L)oad File:
```

This might be a useful warning to many people but as a developer, I frequently want to view the unmodified version as I rewrite sections of code in the adjacent terminal. Meaning I want to compare the original logic to the new logic without an annoying warning popping up all the time.

I do not want the view instance to `autoload`. I have seen references to `FileChangedShell` but it's not at all clear how to use that to disable this warning. Setting `set buftype=nofile` as explained `:help ignore-timestamp` results in an error `E382: Cannot write, 'buftype' option is set` when trying to save changes in the vi instance.

Please explain how I can disabled this warning message. I do not see why this message would be appropriate if the file is opened read-only using `view` and even if it wasn't it should not pro-actively warn if I have not tried to make a change. Vi already warns when you try to commit a modification to a file that has changed which is enough warning IMO.

Comment: Per `:h W11` it happens when you're editing a file and another program has changed the contents/timestamp. So there are two different versions. If you're not aware of this then you may lose the version you actually want to keep. That's a destructive edit. If you're saying something else is happening then please be more specific in your question. "Viewing the same file in different terminals" is kind of vague.

Comment: It _sounds_ like you have the file open for editing in one instance, and opened for viewing (as in `view file`) in another, and the viewed file detects the edited file has changed. In that case, you may want to see `:help ignore-timestamp` and/or `:help :DiffOrig` and/or use `git diff`/`git diff --cached` prior to a commit (assuming git).

Comment: I think `buftype` needs to be set in the `view` instance only.

Comment: Setting `buftype` on the `view` instance only does avoid the warning. Is there a way to persistently apply settings to `view` only? But this also seems to be a bit of a hack since it's not really disabling the warning. It's changing the behavior of view in a fundamental way. If I wanted to write changes in view with `:w!` that would not work and generate the `E382` error.

Comment: Well, you can't have your cake and eat it too. You can launch view with commands to set this (using the `+`/`-c`/`--cmd` options). I highly recommend using your version controls diff capabilities or looking at `:help :DiffOrig`.

Comment: @D. Ben Knoble - Your comments are really are just deflective at this point. Using a global setting to fix one problem at the expense of another is not having cake and eating it too, it's wach-a-mole. It should be obvious that I do not want to add a bunch of arguments every time I want to edit a file. I probably execute vi a 100 times a day. Clearly there should be a way to disable this warning and your comments can only server to delay the fix.

Comment: My cake comment is specific to trying to `:w!` in `view`. Not that you can’t do that, but it’s sort of against the grain; with the buftype “hack” it’s obviously not going to work, but I didn’t know you needed to combine those (do you?). Re: args, shell functions can save that tedium. And you still have not responded to requests to try git diff or DiffOrig. But perhaps I am being deflective, or at least challenging the frame of the question, so I will step back at this point. (FWIW I use only vim to edit files all day, and I don’t have this issue, because we have different workflows.)